# Add-Ins cannot load into Office 2007

Tags: vsto, office-addins

I deploy a VSTO 4 file like picture below

[image: registry WordAddIn]

[image: WordAddIn is loaded into Word 2007 Program - Win XP]

It work well in a lot of Computers but some computers my AddIn cannot show. I have checked on the check box in the second picture, but when I restart Word Program and open the dialog "Com Add-Ins" a gain the check box is not checked. My AddIn is not shown.

I have build my AddIn in Visual Studio 2010, output VSTO 4. I deploy into Win XP and Word 2007, .net 4 is installed at the computers.

Please tell me what is the problem, how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem as you in one system with excel addin, when the user opened her excel file, the addin was not exist, in this case when I opened excel from start menu and  clicking on office button and opening file from there the addin appeared
it is temporary solution, after while when she re-installed the office the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you get an unhandled exception in the code of the add-in.

> when I restart Word Program and open the dialog "Com Add-Ins" a gain the check box is not checked. My AddIn is not shown.

Microsoft Office applications can disable add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your add-in, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when an add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the Startup event handler in your add-in is executing.

Soft disabling can occur when an add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable an add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the Startup event handler is executing.

When you re-enable a soft-disabled add-in, the application immediately attempts to load the add-in. If the problem that initially caused the application to soft disable the add-in has not been fixed, the application will soft disable the add-in again.

Read more about that in the [How to: Re-enable an Add-in That Has Been Disabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268871.aspx) article.

Also you can check out the Trust center setting in the host application.